# Compute Percentage Change for TimeSeries

Tags: time-series

Given a TimeSeries, ts, how can I compute the percentage change from one period to the next?  Percentage change is calculated as (x[n] - x[n-1])/x[n-1] * 100.0.  I've tried experimenting with MovingMap and pure functions but without success.

I can get the percentage change as a list of values with:

```
pc = MovingMap[(#[[2]] - #[[1]])/#[[1]] * 100.0 &, ts["Values"], {2}]
```

pc can then be plotted with ListLinePlot, but I'd really like to get back a TimeSeries object that can be plotted with DateListPlot.

Answer (score 3):

It matters if your `TimeSeries` is `RegularlySampledQ` or not. If it is, then you can use

```
f = If[PossibleZeroQ[#1], Missing["Indeterminate"], 100 (#2 - #1) / #1]&;
MovingMap[f @@ #Values &, ts, {1, Right}]
```

otherwise you can use

```
MovingMap[f @@ #Values &, ts, {Quantity[2, "Events"], Right}]
```

where `f` is defined as in the previous code block. This time though, you are calculating a percentage difference that is not commensurate along the series, as it corresponds to different time spans.

Comment: The TimeSeries comes from FinancialData and appears not to be RegularlySampledQ.  Simplifying to:
`MovingMap[100 (#2 - #1) / #1 & @@ #Values &, ts, {Quantity[2, "Events"], Right}]`
works nicely.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not too hard:

```
ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData["SBUX", "2016"]];
pc = TimeSeries[100. Differences[#]/Most[#] &[ts["Values"]], {Rest[ts["Dates"]]}];

DateListPlot[{ts, pc}, PlotLegends -> {"SBUX Close", "% change"}]
```

[image: time series and its percentage change]

Comment: Thank you.  The computation of pc is elegant and a nice expression of the Wolfram Language.