# Mathematica 12.x: Don't use Accumulate or Differences on Around objects!

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, error-propagation, around

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.2 or later**

---

It seems we've discovered a bug! The following is a summary of the problem and possible workarounds. Scroll down to ORIGINAL POST to see the original statement of the issue.

If a `List`, `TimeSeries`, etc. of `Around` objects contains *any* identical elements, `Accumulate` produces propagated uncertainties that are too large. `FoldList[Plus, 0, list]` and `FoldList[Plus]@list` are valid alternatives that do not present this issue for `Lists`, *but these do not work with* `TimeSeries`! Finding something which does work with `TimeSeries` is still a work in progress.

If a `List`, `TimeSeries`, etc. of `Around` objects contains *consecutive* identical elements, `Differences` produces `0.`, which does not have an associated uncertainty. `MovingMap[Subtract[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &, list, 1]` and `MovingMap[Subtract[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &, #, 1] &@list` are valid alternatives which do not present this issue. And they work with `TimeSeries`!

Analysis of these and other functions can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoU6UGb8wJ2AhccW2OmI6L8hK5Sm2Q).

For now, my best solution is to create a symbolic `TimeSeries` to manipulate with `Accumulate`, `Differences`, `Ratios`, etc., and then use `ReplaceAll` to insert the `Around` data in the final step. I'm not using `AroundReplace` because that function took over ten minutes to process a single `TimeSeries`! But, one must be careful when using `ReplaceAll` in lieu of `AroundReplace`. According to the documentation,

> [`ReplaceAll` and `AroundReplace`] coincide if each replaced variable appears once in the original
> expression.

One must therefore perform calculations in a manner that ensures this is the case.

------------------------------------ORIGINAL POST------------------------------------

I am working with several `TimeSeries` containing `Around` objects. I find that the propagated uncertainties for numerical values are larger than I expect them to be. In contrast, the propagated uncertainties for symbolic values are exactly what I expect them to be.

This is also true for lists of `Around` objects, so I will use `List` to demonstrate. Note that the original data values are all integers greater than or equal to zero (`0 ≤ n[i] ∈ ℤ`) and their original uncertainties equal their square roots (`δn[i] = √n[i]`)

First, generate a list of symbolic data:

`symbolicData = Table[Around[n[i], Sqrt[n[i]]], {i, 10}]`

[image]

Then, `Accumulate` these data:

`symbolicTotals = Accumulate@symbolicData`

[image]

The uncertainty of the last value is the square root of that value:

`{symbolicTotals[[-1]]["Uncertainty"], Sqrt@symbolicTotals[[-1]]["Value"]}`

[image]

Given my understanding of error propagation, this is correct.

Now, generate numerical data:

`numericalData = Table[Around[#, Sqrt[#]] &@RandomInteger[10], {i, 10}]`

[image]

`Acculumate` these data:

`numericalTotals = Accumulate@numericalData`

[image]

Compare the last value's uncertainty and square root:

`{numericalTotals[[-1]]["Uncertainty"], Sqrt@numericalTotals[[-1]]["Value"]}`

[image]

The uncertainty is larger than the square root. This happens for any long list of numbers.

Why? And how can I fix it? (Assuming there's an actual problem here, and not simply a lack of knowledge on my end.)

My *guess* is that this discrepancy is a consequence of the fact that

> When Around is used in computations, uncertainties are by default propagated using a first-order series approximation, assuming no correlations.

What exactly is being approximated here, and if `Around` *always* does this, why doesn't it affect symbolic values?

I understand that `AroundReplace` allows for higher-order approximations, but it starts with a symbolic expression and substitutes numerical values. I'm *starting* with numerical values. Is my only option to generate `TimeSeries` objects with symbolic values, do all my computations, and then `AroundReplace` the symbols with the original numerical data?

Is there a better way?

------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

@JulienKluge, @SjoerdSmit, and @JimB have suggested and demonstrated that this is a bug in `Accumulate`. I've done my own investigation, and I agree. `Accumulate` produces incorrectly propagated uncertainty whenever the same `Around` object appears multiple times in whatever is being accumulated. This error seems to increase with the number of duplicates.

`Accumulate` is not the only function with an issue. When the same `Around` object appears consecutively in a list, `Differences` produces a zero with no uncertainty!

[image]
(If you'd like a copy of the notebook in which I performed this investigation, [click here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoU6UGb8wJ2AhccW2OmI6L8hK5Sm2Q).)

I've encountered the problem with `Differences` before, but I'm only now recognizing it as a serious issue. I suppose bugs like this are why `Around` is still an experimental function...

In light of everything, I think I will try doing all my calculations on symbolic `TimeSeries` objects and finishing them off with `AroundReplace`. Hopefully, that will circumvent the `Accumulate` and `Differences` issues as well as some other minor problems I've encountered. If that doesn't work, I'll compute the uncertainty bands myself...

Wish me luck!

------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

`AroundReplace` took over ten minutes to replace the values of a symbolic `TimeSeries` with `Around` objects. No other functions such as `Accumulate` had yet been used. So, I won't be using `AroundReplace`. `ReplaceAll` was much faster, but the documentation suggests it might introduce its own problems when working with `Around`.

Following the advice of @SjoerdSmit, I am going to try using `FoldList[Plus]@list` and `MovingMap[Subtract[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &, #, 1] &@list` as alternatives to `Accumulate` and `Differences`, respectively.

I'll report back if there are any major changes.

Comment: Somehow the "SUMMARY" does not appear to be a question at all, but an answer. It would be nice if the question were clearly posed as a question, and if you have an answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: My apologies. I'm a relatively new active participant here, and I'm still learning the etiquette. The original question lead to the discovery of a bug, and so I modified the original post to alert other users of this fact. I will try to make that more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Update: the bug was fixed in version 12.3

Comment: Excellent! I'll update Mathematica and this post to reflect that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be a bug. Compare, for example:

```
list1 = {Around[1., 2.], Around[1., 2.0001]};
Plus @@ list1
Fold[Plus, 0, list1]
Last @ Accumulate[list1]
```

> Around[2., 2.8284978363081703`]

with

```
list2 = {Around[1., 2.], Around[1., 2.]};
Plus @@ list2
Fold[Plus, 0, list2]
Last @ Accumulate[list2]
```

> Around[2., 2.8284271247461903`]

> Around[2., 4.] (* result from Accumulate*)

I reported the issue. In the mean while you can use:

```
FoldList[Plus, 0, list2]
```

to get a correctly accumulated list.

Comment: For the workaround and for reporting the bug, I'm accepting this answer! Even though I've other problems with `Around` objects, and might have to resort to `AroundReplace` after all...

Comment: @AaronEiben It might be worth trying alternative methods as well. Like I said, `FolList[Plus, 0, list]` is a valid alternative for `Accumulate` and such alternatives exist for `Differences` as well. For example, `#2 - #1 & @@@ Partition[Range[5], 2, 1]`.

Comment: Agreed. `AroundReplace` took over ten minutes to replace the values in a symbolic `TimeSeries`--one that had not yet been operated upon! `ReplaceAll` was a thousand times faster, but the documentation suggests it will introduce its own problems with `Around` objects if not used carefully.

So, I'm testing `FoldList[Plus]` as an alternative to `Accumulate` and `MovingMap[Subtract[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &, #, 1]&` as an alternative to `Differences`. These seem to work so far, and I'll update the original post as I learn more.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It turns out `FoldList` doesn't play nicely with `TimeSeries`. For example, if ```test = TimeSeries[val /@ Range[0, 9]]``` then ```FoldList[Plus, 0, test]``` produces an error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @AaronEiben Hmmm, not really. You can pull the timeseries apart with `Normal`; then fold the values (keeping the timestamps apart); and then put it all back together. That's the best I've got right now.

Comment: I've been trying that. I wrote the following: ```tsAroundAccumulator := TimeSeries@*Transpose@*(ReplacePart[#, 2 -> FoldList[Plus]@#[[2]]] &)@*Transpose@*Normal```. I also have a version in which the `ReplacePart` function is swapped with ```({#[[1]], FoldList[Plus]@#[[2]]} &)```. Both versions produce correct uncertainties for sample `TimeSeries` composed of random integers, but when I use my actual data, the propagated uncertainties **are still too large!** (But they are *slightly* smaller than what `Accumulate` produces.)

Comment: @AaronEiben Could you post the problem as a new question, please?

Answer (score 13):

Okay, wow. This stumped me for a bit.

But I found the answer. It seems to be a bug. An innocent looking one.

The fact you tried Integers instead of Reals triggered it. (I tried to use Reals first and failed to reproduce)

What happens is the following.  Whenever Accumulate sees two equal values, it multiplies them by two instead of adding them. Which makes sense for reals

```
Accumulate[{a, b}]
Accumulate[{a, a}]
```

> {a, a + b}
>
> {a, 2a}

But not for Around's. The multiplication by two yields a different error propagation in the standard linear Gaussian approach

```
Accumulate[{a,b}]/.{a->Around[v,d],b->Around[v,d]}
Accumulate[{a,a}]/.{a->Around[v,d]}
```

> {v±d,2 v±Sqrt[2] Sqrt[d^2]}
>
> {v±d,2 v±2 d}

Judging from the comments, seems to be a bug. Someone/You should file it with Wolfram.

> 12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)

Comment: No, I think this is correct. Adding two different numbers with uncorrelated errors is different from adding the same number with the same error to itself. In the first case, the errors partially cancel because they're uncorrelated, which gives a smaller error overall. That's why `AroundReplace` exists along with `ReplaceAll`. Compare, e.g., `AroundReplace[a + Sqrt[a], a -> Around[2., 0.3]]` with `ReplaceAll[a + Sqrt[a], a -> Around[2., 0.3]]`. In the second case, the two terms are assumed to be uncorrelated.

Comment: Ahh darng...yes I think you are correct. This gotcha hit me already multiple times since I started using Around. Thanks.

Comment: No wait, wouldn't that mean, that Accumulate implicitly assumes the values to be the same and thus dependent?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit.  I agree with Julien Kluge in that it's an `Accumulate` bug rather than an issue with `Around`.  Consider a non-integer common value with the same uncertainty:  `Accumulate[{Around[4.5, 4], Around[4.5, 4]}][[2]]` gives `Around[9., 8.]` when it should give `Around[4.5 + 4.5, Sqrt[4^2 + 4^2]]` which is `Around[9., 5.656854249492381]`.  But if the uncertainties are different, then it gives the expected answer:  `Accumulate[{Around[4.5, 4], Around[4.5, 6]}][[2]]` results in `Around[9., 7.211102550927978]` which is what `Around[4.5 + 4.5, Sqrt[4^2 + 6^2]]` produces.

Comment: In short `Accumulate[{Around[a, b], Around[a, b]}][[2]]` results in `Around[2 a, 2 b]` when it should result in `Around[2 a, 2^Rational[1, 2] b]` whether `a` is real or an integer.  And `Accumulate[{Around[a, b], Around[a, c]}][[2]]` results in the expected answer:  `Around[2 a, (b^2 + c^2)^Rational[1, 2]]`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see now. This is definitely confusing. It seems like you can obtain the right behaviour with `Accumulate[{Around[a, b], Around[a, b2]}][[2]] /. b2 -> b`. You can also see that `Accumulate[{Around[1, 2.], Around[1, 2.0]}][[2]]` is different from `Accumulate[{Around[1, 2.], Around[1, 2.0001]}][[2]]`. That's definitely a bug. I'll file it today.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @SjoerdSmit for filing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment but I will note that `Accumulate` can be particularly tricky with `TimeSeries` objects. This is well documented elsewhere but, in short, `Accumulate` applied to a `TimeSeries` object will interpolate "missing" values if your `TimeSeries` is not, by default, what Mathematica considers to be "Regularly Sampled". There are good reasons "under the hood" why this is the default behaviour but it's a trap for users who are inexperienced with the quirks of `TimeSeries`

To get around this, you can specify that your `TimeSeries` object is regularly sampled when you create it.

For the purpose of this example, assume you have some data ready to be created as a timeseries assigned to `xyz`:

```
newTimeseries = TimeSeries[xyz,TemporalRegularity->True]
```

When you now run `Accumulate` on this `newTimeSeries` object, you should get values as expected...but you may break other functionality by forcing the TemporalRegularity to True if it actually isn't.

Comment: Hopefully my upvote boosts your reputation. The data I'm using is, in principle, regularly sampled with no missing values. I run it through `TimeSeriesResample` and set missing values to 0 before doing any computations. But I'll try your suggestion and see if anything changes. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. One thing I will note is that even regular timeseries -- like a default financial timeseries -- is not regularly sampled. Try using `RegularlySampledQ` on your timeseries to check. If it is false, try the fix i suggested in the answer and see what you get. Good luck and thanks again!

Comment: See also first answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170738/compute-percentage-change-for-timeseries?rq=1

Comment: I used `RegularlySampledQ` before changing anything and found that, indeed, my `TimeSeries` are all regularly sampled. So it still seems this is an issue with `Around`. I've marked it as a bug and it's been reported to Wolfram Research, so hopefully, it gets fixed soon.